# Mostrar dados na tela

Tags: php, sql

Estou gerando gráficos e os dados vem através de uma consulta do banco.

Esses dados são jogados em um array de duas posições.

No Script em "labels" que deve retornar o nome dos vendedores, no caso estão na segunda posição do array [1]

E em "data" deve retornar os valores, que no caso estão na primeira posição do array [0].

Porém se eu manter as duas informações a tela fica em branco,  se eu colocar apenas uma delas ou nomes ou valores funciona.

Alguém saberia me dizer como posso fazer isso funcionar?

```html
<html>

<head>
 <title>Bar Chart</title>
        <script src="chart_master/dist/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="chart_master/Chart.js-master/samples/utils.js"></script>
 <style>
 canvas {
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
 }
 </style>
</head>

<body>
     <?php
      require_once './setaqueryDash.php';
      require_once './conecta.php';
      $resultado = ibase_query($CONEXAO_TERM, QueryDashDesafios(substr($loja_selecionada, 0,3),$data_dash));//executa query e armazena o resultado em um array
     ?>
 <div  style="width: 100%;">
  <canvas id="desafios"></canvas>
 </div>
       
 <script>
                var color = Chart.helpers.color;
                var horizontalBarChartData = {
                labels:  [
                    <?php
                         while ($dash1 = ibase_fetch_row($resultado)){
                            echo "'" .trim($dash1['1'])."',";
                         }
                  ?>
                ],
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Desafios',
                    backgroundColor: color(window.chartColors.red).alpha(0.5).rgbString(),
                    borderColor: window.chartColors.red,
                    borderWidth: 3,
                    data: [
                    <?php
                         while ($dash1 = ibase_fetch_row($resultado)){
                            echo trim($dash1['0']).',';
                         }
                    ?>
                    ] 
                    }]

                };
  window.onload = function() {
   var ctx = document.getElementById('desafios').getContext('2d');
   window.myHorizontalBar = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'horizontalBar',
    data: horizontalBarChartData,
    options: {
     // Elements options apply to all of the options unless overridden in a dataset
     // In this case, we are setting the border of each horizontal bar to be 2px wide
     elements: {
      rectangle: {
       borderWidth: 2
      }
     },
     responsive: true,
     legend: {
      
     },
     title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Desafios'
     }
    }
   });

  };
 </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Executa o `var_dump($dash1);` dentro do seu `while`, veja o que aparece.

Comment: Consegui fazer aparecer os dados na tela,  porém,  minha consulta retorna 4 registros mas na tela só aparecem 3,  coloquei o código dessa forma. 

while ($dash1 = ibase_fetch_row($resultado)){
                            echo trim($dash1['0']).',';
                         }

Eu não consigo entender porque dos 4 registros aparecem só 3

Comment: @AlexandrePrezzi coloque essa informação na sua questão. Todos os detalhes que puder lá colocar são importantes para encontrar uma solução.

Comment: @JoãoMartins dei uma alterada na pergunta, veja se ficou mais claro e caso precise de mais informações me avise. Obrigado